# SQL - How to filter out responses with no variation for survery collection to do multi-linear regression?

Tags: sql, variables, filter

I'm new to SQL and I am trying to filter out responses with no variation for survery collection (invalid responses) to do multi-linear regression. Do take note that there is actually more than 100 records for this table and I have simplified it for the illustration.

Database: MySQL 8.0.30 : TLSv1.2 (TablePlus)

- ID is the respondent number.
- Variables - x1, x2, x3 is the independent variables.
- Values - Survery response.

For example this is the current table I have:

| ID | Variables | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x1 | 1 |
| 1 | x2 | 1 |
| 1 | x3 | 1 |
| 2 | x1 | 2 |
| 2 | x2 | 3 |
| 2 | x3 | 4 |
| 3 | x1 | 5 |
| 3 | x2 | 5 |
| 3 | x3 | 5 |

Scripts used:
*SELECT ID, Variables, Values
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ID*

I am trying to achieve the following table, where I only want to keep the records which have a variation in the responses:

| ID | Variables | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | x1 | 2 |
| 2 | x2 | 3 |
| 2 | x3 | 4 |

I have tried to use the functions WHERE, DISTINCT, WHERE NOT, HAVING, but I can't seem to get the results that I require, or showing blank most times (like the table below). If anyone is able to help, that would be most helpful.

| ID | Variables | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you please add database and version details to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has two parts so you are going to need to use a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) for this.

1. you want to know which responses have variations. For this you'll want to **group by** the responses by the `id`, and then check that the responses that have the same `id` all have the same `value`, or not. For this you can select only those **having** more than one **distinct** value:

```sql
select `id`
from results 
group by `id`
having count(distinct `values`) > 1
```

2. based on that you can just wrap it with a `select` to get all the fields that you want, ungrouped:

```sql
select *
from results
where `id` in (
  select `id`
  from results 
  group by `id`
  having count(distinct `values`) > 1
)
```

This is MySQL syntax, but shouldn't have that many differences for main dbs

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a266f806/4/0

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
WITH ids_with_variations as 
(
SELECT ID
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Values]) as unique_value_count
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Values]) = 3 -- this assumes that you expect each ID to have exactly three responses
)

SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ids_with_variations)
```

This is TSQL dialect. This also assumes that you expect exactly three variations in the `value` column.